# Parallas scrolling without fixed background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

Hello everyone I want to make the transition between sections on my webpage [like here:](https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)
but my backgrounds of sections can't be fixed they must have `background-attachment: scroll;`
Is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Keith Clark has written [an excellent article on how to make a parallax website using pure CSS](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/pure-css-parallax-websites/). No need for javascript or jQuery!